# Can some one give example or resource on Dynamic Case Management in OpenText Appworks

Tags: bash, opentext

I just started learning OpentText AppWorks. Please, Help me in understanding dynamic case management using workflow in OpenText AppWorks with any screenshots (please provide Sample workflow).

Comment: Are you just looking for something like shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Smxhv4eOF1w ? Otherwise please add more information.

Comment: I want to learn from scratch, If you have any Practice material that would help, specifically about dynamic case management using workflow